# Why am I getting "record not on file (138)" on progress4GL

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm trying to check if a record exists, otherwise I want to create it.

*For example,*

I've got a `<table>` that doesn't have a `tab-code` equals to `2`, so `it is not available`, then I do another `find` just to "call" the table to create a new item, but for some reason it doesn't "call" the table and I get a beautiful standard error: `record <table> is not on file (138).`

I'm still new to progress4GL, so if it's stupid I apologize profusely.

```
find <table> where tab-code = 2.

if not avail <table>
then do:

    find last <table> no-lock no-error.

    create <table>.
    assign <table>.tab-code = 2.

end.
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve by "call"ing the table.  Maybe it is just an artifact as a result of converting real code into an example but that "FIND LAST" accomplishes exactly nothing in the code that is shown.

Comment: @TomBascom indeed, I used that find last just because I was trying to have the table "opened" because the first find wasn't working*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find <table> where tab-code = 2 NO-ERROR.
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, a simple mistake, my bad :/ +1.

Answer (score 0):

Always use NO-LOCK NO-ERROR when you find the record. If not using NO-ERROR then it will give an error after the compilation(means if the record is not available).

```
FIND FIRST <table> NO-LOCK WHERE <table.id>  = 2 NO-ERROR.

IF NOT AVAILABLE <table> THEN DO:
   CREATE <table>.
   ASSIGN <table>.<table_id> = 2 NO-ERROR.
END.
 /*always use FIND FIRST to get record from the particular table. FIND case will fail some time */
```